# wsDualHttpBinding failing with larger datasets

Tags: wcf, dataset, wsdualhttpbinding

I am using wsDualBinding in my wcf service to handle 2 way communication in my software. Everything seems to work fine except when I call a method to get a customer list. If in the service I limit the results of the query to 2730 records I can get the results in about 1-2 seconds and display them in a datagrid. If I limit the results to 2731 (one more) I get the following Error:

http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/Dispatch_Studio_Server/DispatchService/ did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:00:59.9990000).  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.

In my research I have read that streaming is better for larger datasets so I have also tried setting up a basicHttpBinding endpoint using streaming instead of buffering and I get essentially the same results. 2730 records works fine but 2731 records gives me the following error.

An error (Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.) occurred while transmitting data over the HTTP channel.

I wouldn't exactly call 2730 records a large dataset. This leads me to believe there is something else causing this issue.

Here is my client configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
```

Here is my server configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
```

As you can see I have tried changing the maxMessageReceivedSize and other settings to resolve this issue but to no avail.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you please add the complete configs for client? and server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you should never send such a big amount of data to a client (I doubt the client will perform a task on the complete set of data), you may be hitting the MaxSerializedObjectsInGraph limit.

Try to add a behavior in your configurations containing:

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
```

You may also consider returning a smaller resultset using pagination or filtering.

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent 16+ hours trying to figure this out. I was about ready to cry for my mommy. Now we can continue with our development.